# How long would a day/week/month be in a world where a year was the equivalent to four months here?

Tags: astronomy, day-night

I am new here and I wish for someone to help me with this question that haunts me with writer's block. I am writing a story that is set in a world where each year lasts the same time as four months here.

The world is nothing but an endless forest where everything is massive(roughly 60x the normal size), and dire wolves are plentiful and roam the forest in packs of 6 to 30. There are 5 tribes of humans that live there too but I'm going on a pointless rant because today we're focusing on the lunar cycle of this world. There are three moons, the largest one is the farthest away, but they are rarely seen because of how dense the leaves of the massive trees are. But there are still 365.24 days in each of the years, it's just that the plant's orbital cycle is much faster than Earth's.

If someone could help me make an accurate lunar/day cycle it would really help.

Comment: VTC: needs details or clarity. (1) There is no relationship whatsoever between the duration of a day and the duration of a year. (2) Weeks and months are purely artificial constructs, with no relationship with any natural phenomenon. (Historically, the seven day week is a Near Eastern (European view) / Middle Eastern (American view) / Semitic (olde skoole view) thing, which spread to Europe riding on the Christianity train, and the months of the Julian / Gregorian calendar are a Roman thing. Before they adopted the Hebrew seven-day week, the Romans used an eight-day "nundinal" cycle.)

Comment: OP seems to have some misconceptions, having 365.24 days in a year but a faster orbital cycle doesn't make sense. Or just a poorly phrased question. A year is one orbit of the planet about its star. A day is one rotation of the planet.  Every other unit of time is human attempts to fit those two fixed variables into even divisions. That's why we have leap years, and some months are 31 days some 28 or 30.  Yes true that the Month division does have some relation to the lunar cycle and the zodiac but this is more to break down time divisions useful to humans.

Comment: I was halfway through an answer when you changed your question and invalidated what I wrote and what others have writen. You're a moving target and per the [tour], Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. We need to nail down what your rules are, so VTC:Needs More Details until we can nail down what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JBH I apologize for that. I am not trying to make this a discussion forum. I just wish to find an accurate day-night cycle.

Comment: And we're trying to help you do that. For the record, the measurement of time is a perception, not a universal fact. The velocity of light is a constant - but the identification of that velocity is based on the arbitrary human measurement of time. *Unless you're changing the rules of physics in your world,* which is totally OK on this site, *but we need to know that.* If we assume identical physics and assert that one planet orbits faster than another *but claims to have the same number of days in the year* then there MUST be fewer seconds in the faster planet's days.

Comment: Also, identifying your lunar cycle (which will not be identical by name or intent to Earth's measurement) will require (a) the orbital velocity of your planet and (b) the orbital velocities of all three moons. A multi-moon planet's lunar cycle will be complex... If you want accuracy, we need to know the specifics of your solar system's mechanics - not whether or not there are forests and animals.

Comment: @Los3r_ghost_tale_factory No worries! So it sounds like your days will be ~6 ("Earth") Hours? I would suggest that instead of calling the time divisions months / days etc for familiarities sake. You create division that make sense for your own world to eliminate confusions.

Comment: Above all, I (speaking unofficially for all of us) apologize that you're getting a bit of a beating. Please consider using our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9981/40609) where you can have your question analyzed before it's posted on Main. That will avoid many of these kinds of issues. Cheers.

Comment: You can't edit the question in a way that invalidates existing answer. That's why I have rolled back your edit

Answer (score 4):

The duration of the day and the duration of the year are usually two independents variables.

That the year lasts the equivalent of 4 Earth months doesn't put any constraints on the duration of the day (nor it does that the planet hosts 5 tribes and wolves), therefore you are free to choose the duration that most suits your narration.

Weeks and months are artificial constructs made by us, there is again no reason to choose one convention with respect to another.

Answer (score 3):

#### Day

The length of the day depends on how fast the planet spins, not how fast the planet moves. One day starts at sunrise and lasts until the next sunrise.

Your planet experiences 365.24 days in a period equal to 4 Earth months. This implies that your planet spins 3 times faster than Earth, and thus the length of each day is 1/3 an Earth day, which is approximately 8 hours.

#### Week

The only "rule" about week-length is that it must be a whole number of days. You could have a 2-day week, or a 95-day week. It would be silly to have a week that's 5.2 days long, although I could imagine some really bizarre reason for doing that.

However, while week length is arbitrary, people do try to fit it to the surrounding context so it can be useful. For example, people get a certain amount of rest from their jobs based on the length of the week: 2 days of rest for every 5 days of work. If you have a 95-day week, does that mean everybody has to work 93 days in a row for every 2 days of rest? Or would they work 68 days in a row and then get 27 days off? Shorter weeks allow us to "mix" working days and resting days more thoroughly, which is much better for everybody's health and sanity.

Since you have the same number of days in your year as Earth does, it's reasonable to think they might have the same week length: 7 days.

If your tribes are all pre-industrial, they'll care about different things when choosing their week length. For instance, many religions set aside one day each week for religious stuff. People with no science are probably very superstitious, they will believe in many gods and demons, and they'll feel the need to regularly perform rituals in order to stay in the good graces of the supernatural entities they worship and fear. So, the length of the week may just be: how long do they think it's safe to wait without bribing their gods? If they think their gods are very petty, they might have a 5-day week with one holy day each week.

#### Month

Months are more abstract. Just as with weeks, the length of a month is expected to be a whole number of days, but it does not have to be a whole number of *weeks*; Earth months are not a whole number of weeks (except February, 75% of the time, because of leap day). Importantly, not all months need to have the same length -- on Earth they don't. It's also expected that a year is made up of a whole number of months.

On Earth, there were only 10 months of very similar length (30 or 31 days) until Julius Caesar decided he was so important that he was going to create two months named after himself, and the rest of humanity let him get away with it. Now we have 12. Before that, the month was based largely on the cycles of the moon, which is *roughly* 28 days.

Your planet has 3 moons. This could very easily lead to some super-complicated months, if they try to take into account the cycles of all three moons. Or perhaps they pick just one moon and based their month on its cycle.

Comment: Or they might have a polycalendar like the mesoamerican haab/tzolkin combination...

Answer (score 1):

edit:

it seems like you're asking for help with the mathematics of this world. in that case, your planet orbits around your sun and rotates around its axis three times faster than the earth. this would mean eight hour days, 20 second minutes, and so on. weeks and months can retain their value in days, but they'll be three times shorter.

original answer:

**It doesn't matter**

If your world is a planet, or an object orbiting another celestial object, it really doesn't matter. it's up to you.

the earth completes a full rotation around the sun every 365 days because of the speed at which it orbits the sun. the earth has 24 hour days because of the speed it rotates about its axis. these are two different variables.

weeks/months should be relative to the day length, but they're subjective. each tribe could have its own time system, even.